# H2O.ai MOJO dependencies

Tags: jvm, dependencies, h2o

When setting up [h2o.ai for production](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html) the documentation tells you how "Build and extract a model" which ultimately leads you to

> Download the MOJO and the resulting h2o-genmodel.jar

What I'm wondering, is if that `h2o-genmodel.jar` is really tied to the mojo zip file, or if one jar can work with multiple different model zips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest h2o-genmodel.jar will work with all MOJO files. (Note that this is not the case for POJOs or with early versions of the h2o-genmodel.jar.)

I can update the documentation to include this clarification.

Comment: That would be great, as is it's pretty confusing, especially since the documented way to get the h2o-genmodel.jar is in the model export along with the mojo.

Comment: While you're looking this direction, maybe you could check out this other H2O question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749476/h2o-ai-h2o-genmodel-jar-contains-sl4j-binding